# Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and I can't even get it to properly run on my system when copying code from their documentation. When I do I get the error:

`Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.`

I haven't the slightest clue how to fix this and all the other posts on stack I have found are not helpful at all.

As soon as I go to type something into the text field I get the error above in my console on my web browser. Could I have something configured wrong? I don't even know where to start to debug. Any help as to where to start to debug I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my code:

app.js

```
    angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(input, uppercase) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      out = input.charAt(i) + out;
    }
    // conditional based on optional argument
    if (uppercase) {
      out = out.toUpperCase();
    }
    return out;
  };
})
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'reverseFilter', function($scope, reverseFilter) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
  $scope.filteredGreeting = reverseFilter($scope.greeting);
}]);
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <!-- includ the app -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/database.rest.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <input ng-model="greeting" type="text"><br>
  No filter: {{greeting}}<br>
  Reverse: {{greeting|reverse}}<br>
  Reverse + uppercase: {{greeting|reverse:true}}<br>
  Reverse, filtered in controller: {{filteredGreeting}}<br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `ngApp` to somewhere in the HTML, such as the `<html>` or `<body>` tag matching your `angular.module()` identifier, in this case `'myReverseFilterApp'`.

Also you need to make sure you serving the files, [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) for example uses `http-server` npm module to serve files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myReverseFilterApp">

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
      <!-- include the app -->
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/database.rest.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div ng-controller="MyController">
          <input ng-model="greeting" type="text">
          <br> No filter: {{greeting}}
          <br> Reverse: {{greeting|reverse}}
          <br> Reverse + uppercase: {{greeting|reverse:true}}
          <br> Reverse, filtered in controller: {{filteredGreeting}}
          <br>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

As a test, try removing any JavaScript references other than the base angular files as well as your angular code. The cause of this may be associated with a 3rd party file/module executing deprecated code. Perhaps `database.rest.js` may be causing this or other files that aren't displayed here.

Comment: Even after adding the ng-app name I still receive the error thing in the console.

Comment: Make sure you are using the most recent version of `angular` and `angular-resource` if you can. This could be coming from other linked JS files. Try removing reference `database.rest.js` and anything other than `angular`, `angular-resource`, and your `app` JavaScript files. This error can come from other libraries that are executing outdated functions.

Comment: Also try either disabling browser extensions that you may running or load this in a different browser and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Got it to work. I can't copy and paste from the angularjs docs and have it work...I have to type it out. Thank you Alex for pointing out not having ng-app in there though, that helps. Still a noob. :)